# python dictionary to numpy array slicing

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, numpy-slicing

I have a dictionary.

`cars_dict= { 'cars_per_cap': [809, 731, 588, 18, 200, 70, 45], 'country': ['United States','Australia','Japan','India','Russia','Morocco','Egypt'], 'drives_right': [True, False, False, False, True, True, True] }`

I changed it into NumPy by doing

`cars_numpy = np.array(cars_dict)`

`cars_numpy = array({'cars_per_cap': [809, 731, 588, 18, 200, 70, 45], 'country': ['United States', 'Australia', 'Japan', 'India', 'Russia', 'Morocco', 'Egypt'], 'drives_right': [True, False, False, False, True, True, True]}, dtype=object)`

****I want to do slicing and get 'United states' from it****

`print(cars_numpy[1][0])` is not working.

error I get is this

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-54a4195f7446> in <module>
----> 1 print(cars_numpy[1][0])

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: Calling `numpy.array` on a dict doesn't make sense. Why did you do that?

Comment: I second this. Why can't you do `print(cars_dict['country'][0])`?

Comment: I want to understand the behavior that how NumPy will act if I pass a dictionary to it and then try to slice it. i still don't understand why it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is not a list, you cant pass it to numpy and expect the same results, its not ordered, it uses an internal data structure in order to be efficient.

What you could do is:

```
cars_numpy = np.array(list(cars_dict.values()))
```

Which will put them into an array, but you cannot guarantee the order between the keys using this method, e.g. the row of `country` might be before `cars_per_cap`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few things to suggest -

1. You need a nested list instead of a dictionary to create a multi-dim NumPy array. This is available using `list(dictionary.values())`.
2. Using `np.array(dictionary)` will give you a NumPy array with a single entry that holds the dict. Therefore the error `IndexError: too many indices for array` because you are asking for a row and column, but it only has a single element at `arr[0]`
3. `arr[1][0]` is a highly inefficient way of using numpy. Instead, try `arr[1,0]`
4. **Dictionaries are now insertion ordered.** As of Python 3.6, for the CPython implementation of Python, dictionaries remember the order of items inserted. Changing them to numpy arrays (their `values()`) will retain this order.

Therefore this would work -

```
np.array(list(cars_dict.values()))[1,0]
```

```
'United States'
```